How do I identify and fix what is waking my system after suspend?
Since moving from LinuxMint 21.3 (6.5 kernel) to LinuxMint 22 (6.8 kernel), my system will not remain suspended.  I've gone as far as to install a completely new, fresh install on a new partition to test this and have the same results.  It will suspend but immediately awakens.
System Specs:
MB: Gigabyte B550 Aorus Pro V2, BIOS: F18d (latest)
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X
Kernel: 6.8.0-49-generic x86_64
Wake-on-LAN: Disabled
SVM: Enabled

(complete inxi -xxxF is at termbin.com)
NOTE: One thing I have noticed is that my drive LED flashes every two seconds. This happens even when the system is just sitting there.  I do not remember noticing this previously; it may've, I just don't remember seeing it.  I realize system activity can be happening without user action but seeing this made me wonder if it might be related.
Going through the output from journalctl, I found this line:
NetworkManager[1270]: <info>  [1733931932.9428] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)

which seems to indicate that resume was initiated by the NetworkManager.  Below are (I believe) the pertinent sections to show the process but the entire output for this section is at termbin.com
Dec 11 08:45:25 brawn systemd-logind[1211]: The system will suspend now!
...
Dec 11 08:45:25 brawn systemd[1]: Reached target sleep.target - Sleep.
Dec 11 08:45:25 brawn systemd[1]: Starting nvidia-suspend.service - NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Dec 11 08:45:25 brawn suspend[6611]: nvidia-suspend.service
...
Dec 11 08:45:25 brawn systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 11 08:45:25 brawn systemd[1]: Finished nvidia-suspend.service - NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Dec 11 08:45:25 brawn systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
Dec 11 08:45:25 brawn systemd-sleep[6625]: Performing sleep operation 'suspend'...
Dec 11 08:45:25 brawn kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
...
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn kernel: ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
...
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn kernel: ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn kernel: LVT offset 0 assigned for vector 0x400
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
...
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn kernel: Restarting tasks ... 
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.3 build 0 week 24 2017
...
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn kernel: PM: suspend exit
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn kernel: thermal thermal_zone1: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd-resolved[1168]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn touchegg[1216]: libinput error: event0  - Power Button: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 2230ms, your system is too slow
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn touchegg[1216]: libinput error: event1  - Power Button: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 2230ms, your system is too slow
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn zed[1224]: Exiting
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn bluetoothd[1184]: Battery Provider Manager destroyed
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd-sleep[6625]: System returned from sleep operation 'suspend'.
...
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[1]: Starting systemd-rfkill.service - Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[1]: Stopped target bluetooth.target - Bluetooth Support.
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[2289]: Reached target bluetooth.target - Bluetooth.
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[2151]: Reached target bluetooth.target - Bluetooth.
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[1]: Started systemd-rfkill.service - Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[1]: Reached target bluetooth.target - Bluetooth Support.
...
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[1]: Finished systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend.
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[1]: Stopped target sleep.target - Sleep.
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[1]: Reached target suspend.target - Suspend.
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd-logind[1211]: Operation 'suspend' finished.
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn ModemManager[1345]: <msg> [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn NetworkManager[1270]: <info>  [1733931932.9428] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn NetworkManager[1270]: <info>  [1733931932.9429] device (eno1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[1]: Starting grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB...
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[1]: Starting nvidia-resume.service - NVIDIA system resume actions...
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[1]: Stopped target suspend.target - Suspend.
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn suspend[6857]: nvidia-resume.service
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd-logind[1211]: Operation 'suspend' finished.
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn ModemManager[1345]: <msg> [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn NetworkManager[1270]: <info>  [1733931932.9428] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn NetworkManager[1270]: <info>  [1733931932.9429] device (eno1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[1]: Starting grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB...
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[1]: Starting nvidia-resume.service - NVIDIA system resume actions...
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn systemd[1]: Stopped target suspend.target - Suspend.
Dec 11 08:45:32 brawn suspend[6857]: nvidia-resume.service

